# Name of GridLayout in Android Studio 3.1 or how can I use it in 3.1?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, grid-layout, android-3.1-honeycomb

What is the name of `GridLayout` in Android Studio 3.1 or how can I use it in 3.1?

[image: here]

Answer (score 10):

You are checking **`GridLayout`** in **`layouts`** category

> While The **`GridLayout`**  is available in **`Legacy`** category

Check this

[image]